# how can i get the any objects age(createdAt - currentDate)?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2

i know the words am using for asking my question is not proper but have no idea about the correct word for any posts's age which is stored in DB of parse.com  ,
  http://wpmedia.o.canada.com/2012/04/final-post-on-instagram-11.png 
in this image you can see what am asking for i want this 49s ago (createdAt - current time) am able to get the post's created date but i don't know what to do next

```
 var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(Post.createdAt)
```

if anything else i have to mention than please let me know , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools) library to achieve this. Example of use:

```
NSDate *timeAgoDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-4];
NSLog(@"Time Ago: %@", timeAgoDate.timeAgoSinceNow);
NSLog(@"Time Ago: %@", timeAgoDate.shortTimeAgoSinceNow);

//Output:
//Time Ago: 4 seconds ago
//Time Ago: 4s
```